# Send data to App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have some code running on my Raspberry Pi (client running Python) that gets my public IP-address every hour. Now I want my IP to send that string to App Engine datastore.

Unfortunatly I do not know how to post data from a client, and all the examples I tried to google seems to handle browser inputs, not posting with Python from a client.

Does anyone know a good tutorial, or have some example code that a novice like me can understand? Maybe some pointers?

[image: here's a drawing I made to explain it for myself]

Comment: do you have an application running on appengine?

Comment: You need to implement `do_POST`, and access the data in the request object. What language is your client on the Pi written in?

Comment: It's supposed to be written in Python 2.7 both on the client and the GAE. For now the client app just writes the string to an XML, but it's suppost to send it to the GAE. I do not have an app on GAE yet, but I should be able to handle the data when it reaches the server - I think.

Comment: Look at the requests library on pypi it massively simplifies building a client code to POST stuff to an appengine app.  https://pypi.python.org/pypi/requests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to send your data as an HTTP POST. As Tim says in the comments, the third-party requests library is a great way to do this, although you can do it with the built-in urllib2.

From the server point of view, getting data from a POST like this is exactly the same as getting it from a form submission.